# ng-multiselect-dropdown select options in a continuous range

Tags: angular, npm, drop-down-menu, multi-select, ng-multiselect-dropdown

I am using [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown) in my Angular 8.3 web SPA. I have a dropdown which has the functionality to select multiple options like so:

[image: Multi-select dropdown]

I need help with selecting the options in a continuous range. For example, as in the image, `Q2` and `Q4` are selected. I want to implement a functionality such that if a user selects `Q2` and `Q4`, `Q3` gets auto-selected. Similarly, if a user first selects `Q3` and then selects `Q1`, `Q2` gets auto-selected. In summary, upon selection of more than 1 quarters in a continuous range will need to be selected. However, if only one quarter (say `Q4`) is selected, the others need not be selected.

**component.html**

```
      <!-- Select quarter -->
      <div class="dropdown ml-2"
      >
        <ng-multiselect-dropdown
          [placeholder]="'Select quarter(s)'"
          [settings]="dropdownSettings"
          [data]="quarterList"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedQuarterList"
          (onDropDownClose)="onDropdownClose()"
          (click)="this.isDropdownOpen = true"
        >
        </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
      </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: "quarterId",
      textField: "title",
      selectAllText: "Select All",
      unSelectAllText: "Clear selection",
      itemsShowLimit: 4,
      allowSearchFilter: false,
    };
}
```

Any help with the same is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ng-dropdown-select store an array in the variable `selectedQuarterList`. The first is order this array, after we get the first and last element of this array (really the index) and select all the values between this one

So, first we add the events `(onSelect)` and `(onDeSelect)`. I choose the same function passing a new argument that is true -if select- or false -if unselect-

```
  <ng-multiselect-dropdown
    ...
      (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event,true)"
      (onDeSelect)="onItemSelect($event,false)"
    >
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

The function onItemSelect becomes like

```
  onItemSelect(event: any, checked: boolean) {
    
    if (this.selectedQuarterList.length > 1) { //almost two elements selected

      //we order the elements acording the list
      const value=this.quarterList.filter(x=>this.selectedQuarterList.indexOf(x)>=0)

      //get the index of the first and the last element
      let first = this.quarterList.findIndex((x) => x == value[0]);
      let last = this.quarterList.findIndex(
        (x) => x == value[value.length - 1]
      );

      //and give the value between this indexs
      this.selectedQuarterList = this.quarterList.filter(
        (_, index) => index >= first && (last < 0 || index <= last)
      );
    }
  }
```

But, with only this code, we can not uncheck an option in middle -imagine you has selected `["Q1","Q2","Q3"]` it's impossible uncheck "Q2" (first get the value 0, last the value 2 and again is selected "Q2"

To take account this we need find the index of the element unselected and change the variables first and last so the function becomes like

```
  onItemSelect(event: any, checked: boolean) {
    if (this.selectedQuarterList.length > 1) {
      const value=this.quarterList.filter(x=>this.selectedQuarterList.indexOf(x)>=0)
      let first = this.quarterList.findIndex((x) => x == value[0]);
      let last = this.quarterList.findIndex(
        (x) => x == value[value.length - 1]
      );

      //we add this condition
      if (last - first + 1 > value.length && !checked) {
        const index = this.quarterList.findIndex((x) => x == event);
        if (index < this.quarterList.length / 2) {
          first = index + 1;
        } else
          last =index-1;
      }

      this.selectedQuarterList = this.quarterList.filter(
        (_, index) => index >= first && (last < 0 || index <= last)
      );
    }
  }
```

you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiselect-dropdown-qv2di2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks. This works, but there's a bug here. If you select only one quarter (say `Q2`) and then unselect it, it  will auto - select the remaining quarters. Ideally, none of the options should have been selected.

Comment: @gourabix, ::glup:: there was an error, the "if" is: `if (this.selectedQuarterList.length > 1)` -the before erroneus code I wrote: "this.quarterList.length", just corrected in code and stackblitz